# issues with Arcgic sdk being used with jacoco coverage report

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android-api, android-jacoco

I have been using esri's arcgis sdk for using maps on my app. Everything was wprking fine until my organization decided to integrate the project with sonarqube and jacoco.
I have done the integration tasks and everyhthing setup. But when i try to run jacoco commands to generate the unit test coverage report for debug build it breaks with the below error.
Please help me to find what can be done to solve this issue.

```
* What went wrong:
```

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexStagingDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:stagingDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform arcgis-android-100.15.0.aar (com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.15.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JacocoTransform: /Users/c_anshul.kumar/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d6ba30801faee8e20758aebedab4fe91/transformed/jetified-arcgis-android-100.15.0-runtime.jar.
> org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationInvocationException (no error message)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexStagingDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:stagingDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :Libraries:libraryjourneyflow) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.4.2, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.jvm.environment=android, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=androidJvm}.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:stagingDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform arcgis-android-100.15.0.aar (com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.15.0) to match attributes {artifactType=jacoco-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JacocoTransform: /Users/c_anshul.kumar/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d6ba30801faee8e20758aebedab4fe91/transformed/jetified-arcgis-android-100.15.0-runtime.jar.
> org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationInvocationException (no error message)